Understanding and improving coherence values using Mallet
I am attempting to run an LDA topic model using Mallet. My corpus consists of user comments from news websites. It's a relatively small corpus with approx. 614k words.
The first approach I took was to split these words across just a dozen, very large documents. I got results but they were not very good, which retrospectively I believe was to be expected. I have now increased the number of documents by chunking the corpus in 614 documents equally with 1k words each. Using this approach I find it much easier to identify topics (and more topics) via the top words, they just seem to be topically more in line. On the other hand, however, I now get much "worse" coherence and exclusivity scores. Using just a dozen documents, coherence was somewhere between -12 (best) and -200 (worst). With the hundreds of documents now, coherence value spread from -120 (best) to -1000 (worst). I used the same parameters for both approaches (Gibbs Sampling of 1000 and optimization intervall set at 10).
I guess my questions are:

Is it correct to assume that the number of documents has an impact on the average coherence value or am I missing something else?
Is there a rule of thumb of some sort that would help me define what a good coherence score is? I am guessing there isn't but just wanted to check if anyone has an idea.

Many thanks in advance!

In general, more documents provide LDA with more contextual information and help LDA to better capture topics. And too short documents may lead to confusion between topics because the vocabulary within a single document is not sufficient to provide clear topic boundaries. And UMass, C_V, C_UCI etc are all good criteria for your coherence explore.
